# This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card number and type

Tags: php, paypal

Using Paypal's DoDirect Payment method I am getting `This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card number and type.` error.

I have entered correct Visa card number, Exp. date, and Correct US address with correct zip code.

I have check this error on paypal. Its showing me `Invalid Data`.

I am using sandbox account for test with test visa card number provided by paypal.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks

`EDITED`

I am getting below error.

```
DoDirectPaymentResponseType Object

(
 [Amount] => BasicAmountType Object
    (
        [currencyID] => USD
        [value] => 0.01
    )

[AVSCode] => 
[CVV2Code] => 
[TransactionID] => 
[PendingReason] => 
[PaymentStatus] => 
[FMFDetails] => 
[ThreeDSecureResponse] => 
[PaymentAdviceCode] => 
[Timestamp] => 2014-09-23T06:37:51Z
[Ack] => Failure
[CorrelationID] => bb70f300ab2bd
[Errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => ErrorType Object
            (
                [ShortMessage] => Invalid Data
                [LongMessage] => This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card number and type.
                [ErrorCode] => 10527
                [SeverityCode] => Error
                [ErrorParameters] => 
            )

    )

[Version] => 106.0
[Build] => 12932421 )
```

Comment: can you paste the complete response here from the PayPal ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on very limited info you provided. I think you should set the both the server and the client to TEST mode in order to use the test VISA number in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that credit card number is not at all being passed to the PayPal , only the credit card type is being passed . Please check your code and make sure the credit card number is passed to the PayPal .